# Moved partitions to make room for Ubuntu....now Windows is gone?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I was trying to install Ubuntu to work alongside windows. The 'install Ubuntu alongside Windows' option never came up on screen so I clicked the 'something else' option. I made the mistake of moving some partitions around to make room for Ubuntu. As soon it had finished installing the screen in the photo below came up. I backed up everything on an external hard drive before doing this but apparently not Windows. I was just trying to get Ubuntu so I could participate in a Java MOOC. What should I do?

[image: this is the screen I'm stuck at]

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info This is just to see where you are at. Boot-Repair cannot fix most Windows issues. And if you used gparted to move partitions, you have to boot into Windows and run chkdsk immediately. And change to a NTFS partition then needs chkdsk. And grub will not boot a Windows that needs chkdsk nor if hibernated. You probably need to use your Windows repair disk to run chkdsk, cannot run chkdsk from Linux. Or maybe use Boot-Repair to temporarily install a Windows type boot loader.

Comment: How dinI create a boot info summary report?

Comment: I don't think I can boot into Windows from the black screen I'm stuck on. Please see the image at the bottom of the paragraph

Comment: Thats Windows errors, not related to Ubuntu. See link above on Summary Report.